# ImportingConstructor decorator in different projects

Tags: c#, mef

I'm using for the first times these decorators (Export(typeOf) and ImportConstructor).

In a mvvm architecture I have a AppViewModel with the following constructor:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
        public AppViewModel(IEventAggregator events, 
            PatientsManagerViewModel pmvm, TestManagerViewModel tmvm, 
            MainViewModel mvm)
        {

            patientsManagerVM = pmvm;
            testManagerVM = tmvm;
            mainVM = mvm;            
        }
```

and with the following Boostrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell>
    {
        private CompositionContainer container;

        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Start();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            container = new CompositionContainer(
                new AggregateCatalog(
                    AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()
                    )
                );

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();

            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            batch.AddExportedValue(container);

            container.Compose(batch);
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
                return exports.First();

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
        }
    }
```

The application starts without problem.

The problem comes out when i try to access another project, which is responsible for the UnitOfWork, the Repository and all the operations related to the DB.
The project is referenced in the one where my main application is.

I need this object (UOW) inside the PatientsManagerViewModel
In the first time I created a static property called AppUOW in the constructor of the AppViewModel:

```
UOW = new OtherProject.UOW(new RepositoryProvider(new RepositoryFactory));
```

thinking that I could call it from my PatientsManagerViewModel object.

But I think that, since the constructor of the AppViewModel needs a PatientManagerViewModel and this one needs a UOW I can't create a UOW inside the AppViewModel constructor.

So I thought I could make this modification:

```
[Export(typeof(IOtherProjectUOW))]
    public class OtherProjectUOW : IOtherProjectUOW, IDisposable
    {
        [....]

        public OtherProjectUOW()
        {
            CreateDbcontext();

            RepositoryProvider repositoryProvider = new Helper.RepositoryProvider(new RepositoryFactories());
            repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
            RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
        }
```

(N.B: this UOW is in another project)...

and the AppViewModel is modified like this:

```
[Export (typeof(IShell))]
    public class AppViewModel : Conductor<object>, IShell, IHandle<ChangeViewEvent>
    {
        PatientsManagerViewModel patientsManagerVM;
        TestManagerViewModel testManagerVM;
        MainViewModel mainVM;        

        public static IOtherProjectUOW UOW { get; private set; }

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public AppViewModel(IEventAggregator events, 
            PatientsManagerViewModel pmvm, TestManagerViewModel tmvm, 
            MainViewModel mvm, IKantaUOW kuow)
        {
            patientsManagerVM = pmvm;
            testManagerVM = tmvm;
            mainVM = mvm;

            UOW = kuow;          
        }
```

But if i try this i received an error in the Bootstrapper class saying that :

--"Could not locate any instances of contract MainApplication.IShell."--

So I'm quite sure the Export - Import system is not working.

Any help is appreciated.